# Rewrite Rule is not working on Azure App Gateway

Tags: azure, gateway

I need to truncate a part of the URL and I have added a rewrite rule and have associated it with routing rule. The backend health is also fine. But when I am hitting the URL it is not getting updated

Incoming URL:
https://contoso.com/my-web/manage-data/addresses/v1?addressComplete=avenue+de&addressSearchFormat=SINGLE_LINE&country=FR&processMode=FASTCOMPLETION

Expected URL
https://contoso.com/addresses/v1?addressComplete=avenue+de&addressSearchFormat=SINGLE_LINE&country=FR&processMode=FASTCOMPLETION

[image]

Regards,
Sisir

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this by using Override back-end path. No need of Rewrite Rules in this scenario.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-http-settings

[image]